# how can i obtain the same basemaps frames with lat lons, from diferents netcdf files, when i plot it

Tags: netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I have three netcdf files with different grid, I need to plot the three files in three different maps, but with the same geographical limits, without the data being stretched or shrunk to cover the entire box, I have tried with:

m = Basemap (llcrnrlon = -85., llcrnrlat = 8., urcrnrlon = -68., urcrnrlat = 17, rsphere = 6371200., resolution = 'l')

but what basemap does is to adapt the data that was previously defined when reading the netcdf to the box, not cutting the data in the latitudes and longitudes defined in the basemap if not adapting the data to that box.

In synthesis I need the data to be cut at the latitudes and longitudes defined with basemap, so that the three netcdf files are comparable in the three maps I require.

Comment: Can't you use `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` methods with your plots? Just use the same values for xlim and ylim in all your plots.

Comment: If `nc` is a dataset object, what is your output of `nc.variables.keys`?

Comment: Thanks, i did it changing map.makegrid  by map.meshgrid, with this method I could fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, i did it changing map.makegrid by map.meshgrid, with this method I could fix it.